# Multiple cascading paths Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am facing an error when trying to set up foreign key constraints using Entity Framework Core:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Comments_Reviews_ReviewId' on table 'Comments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here are my models:

```cs
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("Review")]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public Review Review { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> UserComments { get; set; } 
    public List<Like> UserLikes { get; set; } 
    public List<Review> UserReviews { get; set; }
    public List<Rating> UserRatings { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public enum Group
    {
        Movies, Books, Games
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string ReviewName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ArtName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Group ArtGroup { get; set; }
    
    public List<ReviewTag> ReviewTags { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    public string ReviewText { get; set; }  
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; } 

    [Range(0, 10)]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> ReviewComments { get; set; }
    public List<Like> ReviewLikes { get; set; } 
}

//I also tried altering relationships

// User to Review relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.UserReviews)
    .WithOne(r => r.User)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

// User to Comment relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.UserComments)
    .WithOne(c => c.User)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

// Review to Comment relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
    .HasMany(r => r.ReviewComments)
    .WithOne(c => c.Review)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ReviewId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Comment: You are getting a Multiple cascading paths error because you have multiple cascade paths. The solution is directly in the error message. What is unclear?

Comment: You're not asking a question. Also, please note that there's already an overwhelming amount of questions on this topic.

Comment: You need to set them all to `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am facing an error when trying to set up foreign key constraints
> using Entity Framework Core:

[image]

Well, based on your error details and scenario,[this is officially known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete). On top of this, We have two ways to handle this scenario therefore, the error:

**1. Change one or more of the relationships to not cascade delete.**

In this scenario, we could make the `User` relationship with `UserDetail` and `Menu` optional by giving it a nullable foreign key property: for instance we can do something like:

```
.IsRequired(false);
```

**Note:** You can check our [official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships)

**2. Configure the database without one or more of these cascade deletes,
then ensure all dependent entities are loaded so that EF Core can
perform the cascading behavior.**

Considering this approach we can keep the `User`, `Review` relationship required and configured for cascade delete, but make this configuration only apply to tracked entities, not the database, thus, instead of this `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);` replace with `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict) .IsRequired(false);`: So we can do somethng like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.UserReviews)
    .WithOne(r => r.User)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

// User to Comment relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.UserComments)
    .WithOne(c => c.User)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    .IsRequired(false);
// Review to Comment relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
    .HasMany(r => r.ReviewComments)
    .WithOne(c => c.Review)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ReviewId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
    .IsRequired(false);

}
```

**Note:** As you may know `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)` or `ClientCascade` allows the `DBContext` to delete entities even if there is a `cyclic ref` or `LOCK` on it. Please read the [official guideline for more details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, but I am still facing the same issue even though I updated every relationship (even unrelated to comment)

Comment: Alright, thanks for your update, well, in that scenario, I will suggest your to implement gradually instead of all together, do you know after adding which entiry relation causing the exception?